# Did Umar (ra) said: "Strip the women of their (good) clothes and they will stay in their homes"?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, women, authenticity

I found this saying of Umar (ra) in Ihya Ulumuddin, Book 12, Chapter 3. Is it authentic?

Comment: It would save time if you quote the chapter or section of Ihya where you found it.

Comment: Book 12 Chapter 3

Comment: Ihya' Uloom ad-Dyn actually has only 4 sections the reference therefore hardly seems helpful. Note that al-Ghazali was very weak in hadith sciences therefore his book includes lot of hair raising narrations.

Comment: Soem Wahabis/Salafis claim that Ghazali RH was very weak in hadith science which is a slander. In fact, most of the hadith in Ihya are not weak. Check this out: https://youtu.be/v0C5hzBf0C4

Comment: Imam al-Ghazaly said so himself. May statement is not about al-Ihya' only, imam al-'Iraaqi wrote a book in which he analyzed the ahadith of al-Ihya' and this usually appears as a footer of the book in many editions.

Comment: Imam never said that he was very weak in hadith. He wasn't an expert in hadith for sure. Anyway, many did takhrij on Ihya and found most hadiths has sanad. It's well explained in the video I shared. Do check it out.